# How can I display all of my inputs into one JOptionPane instead of one window at a time?

Tags: java, echo, joptionpane

Below is my code. I am very new to Java and programming in general this is my 2nd day in class, when i run this i end up being able to only open one dialog box at a time instead of being able to input all of the data and having it all show in the dialog box. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Looking forward to learning more about programming and hopefully one day helping others.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class EchoProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte byteValue;
        short svalue;
        int ivalue;
        long lvalue;
        float fvalue;
        double dvalue;
        char charValue;
        boolean booleanvalue;


        Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a byte value (-128 through 127)");
        byteValue = keyboard.nextByte();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have entered " + byteValue);

        System.out.println("Enter a short value (-32,768 through 32,767)");
        svalue = keyboard.nextShort();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have entered " + svalue);

        System.out.println("Enter a int value (-2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647)");
        ivalue = keyboard.nextInt();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have entered " + ivalue);

        System.out.println("Enter a long value (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 through 9,223,372,036,854,775,807)");
        lvalue = keyboard.nextLong();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have entered " + lvalue);

        System.out.println("Enter a float value (number with decimals)");
        fvalue = keyboard.nextFloat();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have entered " + fvalue);

        System.out.println("Enter a double value (number with decimals)");
        dvalue = keyboard.nextDouble();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have entered " + dvalue);

        System.out.println("Enter a char value (a through z)");
        charValue = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have entered " + charValue);

        System.out.println("Enter a boolean value (true or false)");
        booleanvalue = keyboard.nextBoolean();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have entered " + booleanvalue);
        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a number of options.  You could use a `StringBuilder` and append all the results and generate a single `String`, you could create a `JPanel` and use `JLabel`'s to represent the input and display it on a `JOptionPane` or a `JFrame` or a `JDialog` as you like

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I had looked into using JPanel and Jlabel but to be completely honest it doesnt make any sense to me, would there be a way for you to show me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but here it goes:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class EchoProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Byte byteValue;
        Short svalue;
        int ivalue;
        long lvalue;
        float fvalue;
        double dvalue;
        char charValue;
        boolean booleanvalue;

        JTextField answer1 = new JTextField();
        JTextField answer2 = new JTextField();
        JTextField answer3 = new JTextField();
        JTextField answer4 = new JTextField();
        JTextField answer5 = new JTextField();
        JTextField answer6 = new JTextField();
        JTextField answer7 = new JTextField();
        JTextField answer8 = new JTextField();

        JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel("Enter a byte value (-128 through 127)");
        JLabel jLabel2 = new JLabel("Enter a short value (-32,768 through 32,767)");
        JLabel jLabel3 = new JLabel("Enter a int value (-2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647)");
        JLabel jLabel4 = new JLabel("Enter a long value (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808     through 9,223,372,036,854,775,807)");
        JLabel jLabel5 = new JLabel("Enter a float value (number with decimals)");
        JLabel jLabel6 = new JLabel("Enter a double value (number with decimals)");
        JLabel jLabel7 = new JLabel("Enter a char value (a through z)");
        JLabel jLabel8 = new JLabel("Enter a boolean value (true or false)");

        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        jPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 2));

        Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a byte value (-128 through 127)");
        byteValue = keyboard.nextByte();


        System.out.println("Enter a short value (-32,768 through 32,767)");
        svalue = keyboard.nextShort();


        System.out.println("Enter a int value (-2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647)");
        ivalue = keyboard.nextInt();


        System.out.println("Enter a long value (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 through 9,223,372,036,854,775,807)");
        lvalue = keyboard.nextLong();


        System.out.println("Enter a float value (number with decimals)");
        fvalue = keyboard.nextFloat();


        System.out.println("Enter a double value (number with decimals)");
        dvalue = keyboard.nextDouble();


        System.out.println("Enter a char value (a through z)");
        charValue = keyboard.next().charAt(0);


        System.out.println("Enter a boolean value (true or false)");
        booleanvalue = keyboard.nextBoolean();

        jPanel.add(jLabel1);
        answer1.setText(byteValue.toString());
        jPanel.add(answer1);

        jPanel.add(jLabel2);
        answer2.setText(svalue.toString());
        jPanel.add(answer2);

        jPanel.add(jLabel3);
        answer3.setText(String.valueOf(ivalue));
        jPanel.add(answer3);

        jPanel.add(jLabel4);
        answer4.setText(String.valueOf(lvalue));
        jPanel.add(answer4);

        jPanel.add(jLabel5);
        answer5.setText(String.valueOf(fvalue));
        jPanel.add(answer5);

        jPanel.add(jLabel6);
        answer6.setText(String.valueOf(dvalue));
        jPanel.add(answer6);

        jPanel.add(jLabel7);
        answer7.setText(charValue + "");
        jPanel.add(answer7);

        jPanel.add(jLabel8);
        answer8.setText(booleanvalue + "");
        jPanel.add(answer8);

        jPanel.setVisible(true);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,jPanel,"Information",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```